# Oracle procedure fails to write headers to csv file

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, smtp

I have a stored procedure that reads value from table and sends them as CSV file. I wanted the following to be the headers of the CSV file .

**'ID ,INPUT_DATE ,PAYER ,AMOUNT ,TYPE ,PAYEE-SORTCODE_&_BANK_ACCOUNT_NO ,ADDITIONAL_REMARKS ,COMMENTS ,ACCOUNT_NUMBER ,POLICY_NUMBER ,DATE_OF_BRANCH_CONFIRMATION ,CONFIRMED_BY ,SHEETUPDATE_DATE ,MAILUPDATE_DATE ,DATE-TIME ,USER_ID ,STATUS '**

The procedure reads data from table and adds header and stores in a clob variable . the data looks like this when printed in log before it is added as mail attachment .

[image]

But when it is mailed as attachment it doesnt have a header and only has the data

[image]

Here  is my code :

```
create or replace PROCEDURE         EMAIL_DUMP AS 

l_clob2  clob;
l_attach_text2 clob;
l_attach_text_h2 clob;

v_From VARCHAR2(280) := 'abc';
v_Recipient VARCHAR2(280) := 'efg';
v_Subject VARCHAR2(280) := ' Details';
v_Mail_Host VARCHAR2(230) := 'internal';
v_Mail_Conn utl_smtp.Connection;
crlf VARCHAR2 (32767) := chr(13)||chr(10);
c_mime_boundary   CONSTANT VARCHAR2 (256) := '¿AAAAA000956¿';
v_index integer;
v_len integer;

FC_SV_STATUS_DESC VARCHAR2(100) := 'open';

Record_id  Number ;
Input_date varchar2(100);
Payer varchar2(100);
Amount varchar2(100);
Trans_Type varchar2(100);
Payee  varchar2(100);
Remarks  varchar2(500);
Comments varchar2(500);
Acc_no varchar2(100);
Policy_no varchar2(100);
Branch_of date ;
Confirmed varchar2(100);
Sheet_update date;
Mail_update date;
Upload_time  date;
Upload_id varchar2(100);

CURSOR c2 IS 
   select FC_CA_RECORD_ID as Record_id,FC_CA_INPUT_DATE as Input_date,FC_CA_PAYER as Payer,FC_CA_AMOUNT as Amount,FC_CA_TYPE as Trans_Type,FC_CA_PAYEE as Payee,FC_CA_ADD_REMARKS as Remarks,FC_CA_COMMENTS as Comments,FC_CA_ACC_NO as Acc_no,FC_CA_POLICY_NO as Policy_no,FC_CA_BRANCHCONF_DATE as Branch_of,FC_CA_CONFIRMED_BY as Confirmed,FC_CA_SHEETUPDATE_DATE as Sheet_update,FC_CA_MAILUPDATE_DATE as Mail_update,FC_CA_UPLOAD_TIME as Upload_time,FC_CA_UPLOAD_ID as Upload_id into Record_id,Input_date,Payer,Amount,Trans_Type,Payee,Remarks,Comments,Acc_no,Policy_no,Branch_of,Confirmed,Sheet_update,Mail_update,Upload_time,Upload_id FROM abc where  FC_CA_STATUS =3 ;

BEGIN

l_attach_text_h2 :=
'ID ,INPUT_DATE ,PAYER ,AMOUNT ,TYPE ,PAYEE-SORTCODE_&_BANK_ACCOUNT_NO ,ADDITIONAL_REMARKS ,COMMENTS ,ACCOUNT_NUMBER ,POLICY_NUMBER ,DATE_OF_BRANCH_CONFIRMATION ,CONFIRMED_BY ,SHEETUPDATE_DATE ,MAILUPDATE_DATE ,DATE-TIME ,USER_ID ,STATUS ';

FOR employee_rec2 in c2

LOOP

l_attach_text2 :=      '"' || 
employee_rec2.Record_id        || '","' ||
employee_rec2.Input_date       || '","' ||
employee_rec2.Payer            || '","' ||
employee_rec2.Amount           || '","' ||
employee_rec2.Trans_Type       || '","' ||
employee_rec2.Payee            || '","' ||
employee_rec2.Remarks          || '","' ||
employee_rec2.Comments         || '","' ||
employee_rec2.Acc_no           || '","' ||
employee_rec2.Policy_no        || '","' ||
employee_rec2.Branch_of        || '","' ||
employee_rec2.Confirmed        || '","' ||
employee_rec2.Sheet_update     || '","' ||
employee_rec2.Mail_update      || '","' ||
employee_rec2.Upload_time      || '","' ||
employee_rec2.Upload_id        || '","' ||
FC_SV_STATUS_DESC              ||  '"'  ||chr(13);

l_clob2 := l_clob2||chr(10)||l_attach_text2;

END LOOP;

l_clob2 := l_attach_text_h2 ||chr(13)|| l_clob2;

DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(l_clob2);

v_Mail_Conn := utl_smtp.Open_Connection(v_Mail_Host, 25);

utl_smtp.Helo(v_Mail_Conn, v_Mail_Host);

utl_smtp.Mail(v_Mail_Conn, v_From);

utl_smtp.Rcpt(v_Mail_Conn, v_Recipient);

utl_smtp.OPEN_DATA(v_Mail_Conn);

  UTL_SMTP.write_data(v_Mail_Conn, 'From: ' || v_From || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(v_Mail_Conn, 'To: ' || v_Recipient || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(v_Mail_Conn, 'Subject: ' || REPLACE(v_Subject, '[DATE]',TO_CHAR(sysdate,'DD.MM.YYYY')) || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(v_Mail_Conn, 'MIME-Version: 1.0' || UTL_TCP.crlf);

  UTL_SMTP.write_data(v_Mail_Conn,  'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="' || c_mime_boundary || '"' || UTL_TCP.crlf);

  -- Mail body:
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(v_Mail_Conn, '--' || c_mime_boundary || UTL_TCP.crlf); 
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(v_Mail_Conn, 'Content-Type: text/plain' || UTL_TCP.crlf); 
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(v_Mail_Conn, ' Details' || UTL_TCP.crlf); 

  -- Set up attachment header
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(v_Mail_Conn, '--' || c_mime_boundary || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(v_Mail_Conn, 'Content-Type: text/plain' || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(v_Mail_Conn, 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' || 'myfile.csv' || '"' || UTL_TCP.crlf);

  -- Write attachment contents
  v_len := DBMS_LOB.getlength(l_clob2);
  v_index := 1;

  WHILE v_index <= v_len
  LOOP
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(v_Mail_Conn, DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(l_clob2, 32000, v_index));
    v_index := v_index + 32000;
  END LOOP;

  -- End attachment
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(v_Mail_Conn, UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(v_Mail_Conn, '--' || c_mime_boundary || '--' || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  
utl_smtp.CLOSE_DATA(v_mail_conn);
utl_smtp.Quit(v_mail_conn);

DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('mail send  completed...');

EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ( 'Error raised: '|| DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE || ' - '||sqlerrm);
        system.intranet_utils.INTRANET_LOG_ERRORS('procedure EmailDump',
        system.intranet_utils.INTRANET_GET_ERRMSG, 'Error in EmailDump');
END EMAIL_DUMP;
```

If I edit the mail attachment part like below ,then I'm able to get a proper CSV file as attachment with hearder and data , but then I am unable to add body message to the mail.

```
 UTL_SMTP.write_data(v_Mail_Conn, 'From: ' || v_From || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(v_Mail_Conn, 'To: ' || v_Recipient || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(v_Mail_Conn, 'Subject: ' || REPLACE(v_Subject, '[DATE]',TO_CHAR(sysdate,'DD.MM.YYYY')) || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(v_Mail_Conn, 'MIME-Version: 1.0' || UTL_TCP.crlf);

  UTL_SMTP.write_data(v_Mail_Conn,  'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="' || c_mime_boundary || '"' || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(v_Mail_Conn, UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(v_Mail_Conn,  'This is a multi-part message in MIME format.' || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  

  UTL_SMTP.write_data(v_Mail_Conn, '--' || c_mime_boundary || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(v_Mail_Conn, 'Content-Type: text/plain' || UTL_TCP.crlf);

  -- Set up attachment header
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(v_Mail_Conn, 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' || 'CMTL.csv' || '"' || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(v_Mail_Conn, UTL_TCP.crlf);

  -- Write attachment contents
  v_len := DBMS_LOB.getlength(l_clob2);
  v_index := 1;

  WHILE v_index <= v_len
  LOOP
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(v_Mail_Conn, DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(l_clob2, 32000, v_index));
    v_index := v_index + 32000;
  END LOOP;

  -- End attachment
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(v_Mail_Conn, UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(v_Mail_Conn, '--' || c_mime_boundary || '--' || UTL_TCP.crlf);
```

Can anyone tell me why I cant send a mail with both mail body message and attachment ?

Comment: Because the DB never writes headers, that is a function of what ever client you are using. If your procedure is acting as *its own client* then it write the triggers.

Comment: if the header is in the clob before being written into the csv file, then perhaps you have an issue in client side. Have you tried to read the csv in the server ?

Comment: @RobertoHernandez  I printed the clob before utl_smtp.write .... the clob has headers + data . You can see that in the first image in the question..... Is there a way in which I can write the entire clob as the content of csv file .... I feel that some how the headers line which is the first line of clob is getting skipped

Comment: @Belayer the clob already has headers and data in it ...as you can see it in the first image I shared ... some how when I'm writing the clob as attachment ... the headers line (first line ) is being skipped ....  I dont understand why it does not write the entire clob

Comment: @TJ32, if you have a database directory with privileges for the user who owns the procedure, you can use `DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.clob2file` to write the clob into a file in the database server

Comment: @TJ32 Could you please check what will happened when you try send csv contain only 3 colums

Comment: @ArkadiuszŁukasiewicz  we I tried 3 columns ... i got the same result ..... no headers

Comment: when I remove some C_Mime_boundary part I am able to send proper attachment ...I have added the  code that works for sending the attachment with headers and data ....but when i use that code I am unable to add a body message to mail

Comment: Try to add one empty line before and after email body.

Comment: @ArkadiuszŁukasiewicz could you show an  example